# Serilog not installing in Library project .Net 6

Tags: c#, serilog, .net-6.0

I have a Library project in .net6, I have attempted to install serilog version 2.10 or serilog.AspCore version 5.0 a couple of time but both returned error. I keep getting error`Package Serilog.Sinks.Debug 2.0.0 is not compatible with net6.0` each time. Below is the .csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Does this mean serilog is not available for .net6 library project or I am not getting the version right?

Comment: We need more info to tell. What version of Serilog of Serilog.AspNetCore are you trying to install? Serilog.AspNetCore should be what you need and install just fine.

Comment: That was my expectations too but for reasons I don't know, it will not install.

Comment: Are you going to provide more info? You should give us your .csproj file, the specific version you're trying to install, etc.

Comment: I have updated it with the versions and .csproj

Comment: Can you try manually editing the csproj with the dependencies as shown in the answer from @Maytham and try to build? Rather than installing through what I assume is the Visual Studio interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following project setup and works fine for me:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```